# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

this is logging an error of unexpected end of input..

```
for(var i = 0; i < completedTasksHolder.children.length; i++) {
//bind events to list item's children (taskIncomplete)
bindTaskEvents(completedTasksHolder.children[i], taskIncomplete);
}
```

Comment: The for loop looks fine to me.  Can you please include more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no code is running at all, and the error is flagged as a Syntax Error, your problem is most likely caused by a wrong number of opening and closing brackets or parenthesis before this statement.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem i was missing a curly brace in a function above the loop

Comment: Please use a decent IDE, will help you format the code, follow code indentation, some basic things to start coding with. Will save everyone's time, especially your's.